# Accessing image2D from image2DArray

Tags: opengl, image-unit

I am asking probably a simple question.I have a texture array (GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY) of image2D textures.I access the array in a fragment shader via image2DArray.How do I get an access to the images of the array? imageLoad() has a param for layer number? I have read [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) and [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt) ,but failed to figure out how it's done.

The thing is that if I access it like this:

```
void main(void)
{

color = vec4(imageLoad(output_image, ivec3(gl_FragCoord.xy,0) ).xyzw) / 255.0;
}
```

That is, third number of texture coords is texture layer index.I am getting texture's output onto the screen but it becomes static (doesn't move with cam movement) and displaced.

**UPDATE:**

Ok,it was my fault.I was referencing wrong texture object.Yes, the third coordinate of ivec3 in imageLoad should target texture array layer index.

Comment: No,image2DArray http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store.txt  But I guess the concept should be similar...